# How can I cast a string column containing an array of json records to a list-column in DuckDB?

Tags: json, parquet, duckdb

I am currently using DuckDB to perform data transformation using a parquet file as a source. In this parquet file, I have one column encoded as a string which contains an array of json records:

`[{...}, {...}, {...}]`

I'd like to manipulate this array of record as if it was a list column of jsons.

I tried reading this column with [duckDB scalar function](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.3.3/extensions/json.html#json-functions), but unfortunately, this column is not parsed correctly and I cannot set a json_format in the scalar function as I could have done with the `read_json_objects` function.

Is there anything that I can do to solve this problem?*

---

The following is a reproducible example with the input table and what should be the output table.

```
-- Build the table and populate it with a string 
-- column with an array of json records

CREATE TABLE input(data VARCHAR); 
INSERT INTO input VALUES ('[{"id": "1", "status":"ok"}, {"id":"2", "status":"ok"}]');

-- Build the output table and populate it with 
-- a json column with an list

CREATE TABLE output(data JSON);
INSERT INTO output (data) VALUES (ARRAY['{"id": "1", "status": "ok"}', '{"id": "2", "status": "ok"}']);
```

Comment: Hey @Cedric, could you provide some sample data and the expected output format that would help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some of DuckDB's text functions for your use case.
https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/char

Normally, you can use DuckDB's `string_split` to separate your `VARCHAR` into a list of `VARCHAR`s (or `JSON`s in your case). In your example, the comma inside the `JSON` conflicts with the comma to separate the `JSON`s. My solution might be a bit hacky, but I hope it works for you. I trim off the leftmost and rightmost bracket, then I replace `},` with `}},` to avoid confusion of the comma separator, then I split the `VARCHAR` into a list of `JSON`s with `},` as the separator.

```sql
duckdb> LOAD 'json';
duckdb> CREATE TABLE input(data VARCHAR);
duckdb> INSERT INTO input VALUES ('[{"id": "1", "status":"ok"}, {"id":"2", "status":"ok"}]');
duckdb> CREATE TABLE output_as_json_list(data JSON[]);
duckdb> CREATE TABLE output_as_json(data JSON);

duckdb> INSERT INTO output_as_json_list SELECT string_split(replace(data[2:-1], '},', '}},'), '},') FROM input;
duckdb> SELECT * FROM output_as_json_list;
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ data                                                     │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ [{"id": "1", "status":"ok"},  {"id":"2", "status":"ok"}] │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

duckdb> INSERT INTO output_as_json SELECT UNNEST(data) FROM output_as_json_list;
duckdb> SELECT * FROM output_as_json;
┌────────────────────────────┐
│ data                       │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│ {"id": "1", "status":"ok"} │
│  {"id":"2", "status":"ok"} │
└────────────────────────────┘
```